# if defined?(ActionController) and defined?(ActionController::Base)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Its a code snippet from act_as_audited plugin 1.1.1 under rails/init.rb

Why is this code used? Any general explanation of it is welcomed.

```
if defined?(ActionController) and defined?(ActionController::Base)
```

Comment: I'd have thought because rails is actually essentially a group of gems, and that is a gem that is as it says an ActiveRecord extension. ActiveRecord is only a small part of rails, some people might only have used ActiveRecord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/tree/v1.1.1) is intended to be usable with plain ActiveRecord. As you can use ActiveRecord outside of Rails, e.g. in a Sinatra app, it is helpful if a gem doesn't tie itself to Rails.

This is exactly what is happening here: the authors try to detect if they are running under Rails (or more specifically, if the app uses ActionController for routing which is part of Rails) to load additional Rails-specific functionality.

For apps not using ActionController (or Rails), the gem is thus still usable.

It seems that they have dropped this compatibility layer in later releases. This, the successor of acts_as_audited (called just [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited)) depends on Rails now.